# Different ways of calculating mean in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the mean of a column of a dataframe using some restrictions so first I did:

```
mean(Ykkonen$deltaA[Ykkonen$PH<=2.5], na.rm = TRUE)
```

but I when I try instead

```
Ykkonen %>% filter(PH<=2.5) %>% mean(deltaA, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I get error

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(., deltaA) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Yet `deltaA` is numerical. So I am trying to understand why using the tubes `%>%` is any different?

I mean if I understand it correctly by typing `dataframe %>% filter(a=='s')` it should return only entries that has `s` for the variable `a` , am I right?

Comment: please try to come up with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126). Thus, can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return one value as a numeric vector (with length 1) you can use `pull`:

```
Ykkonen %>% filter(PH<=2.5) %>% pull(deltaA) %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% filter(qsec >= 17) %>% pull(drat) %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 3.561304
```

In order to ensure that the target is numeric, you could also use `summarize_if` like that:

```
mtcars %>% filter(qsec >= 17) %>% summarize_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% pull(drat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a summarise function to get the result you want.

```
Ykkonen %>% filter(PH<=2.5) %>% summarise(mean = mean(deltaA, na.rm = TRUE)
```

You should check what you get returned when you use `Ykkonen %>% filter(PH<=2.5)`. This will be a data.frame (tibble), not a vector. So when you use mean after the filter you are giving a data.frame to the mean, which will result in this error. One of the checks mean performs is :

```
if (!is.numeric(x) && !is.complex(x) && !is.logical(x)) {
warning("argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA")
```

And a data.frame will not pass this test.